# obtener valor de multiples CheckBox seleccionados-React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estoy trabajando con checkBox para mi proyecto, para el ejemplo hay 3 opciones de color y 2 opciones de ocación en forma de CheckBox,el problema esta en que si quiero elegir 2 opciones por ejemplo: fiesta y rojo solo me muestra en el alert una de las dos y no en conjunto como tendria que ser.

intente validar esa opcion como se muestra en codigo pero no funciono y tampoco creo que sea una buena opcion ya que seria muy largo teniendo en cuenta la cantidad de opciones que el usuario podria escoger.

como puedo obtener las dos opciones que escogio el usuario de una buena forma?

gracias

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {
      checkRojo:false,
    checkBlanco:false,
    checkPurpura:false,
    checkFiesta:false,
    checkMatrimonio:false,
   
    };
    }
    
    checkBoxRojo(){
    
      this.setState({ checkRojo: !this.state.checkRojo,id:"rojo" });
    }
    checkBoxBlanco(){
    
      this.setState({ checkBlanco: !this.state.checkBlanco,id:"blanco" });
    }
    checkBoxPurpura(){
    
      this.setState({ checkPurpura: !this.state.checkPurpura,id:"purpura" });
    }
    checkBoxFiesta(){
    
      this.setState({ checkFiesta: !this.state.checkFiesta,id:"fiesta" });
    }
    checkBoxMatrimonio(){
    
      this.setState({ checkMatrimonio: !this.state.checkMatrimonio,id:"matrimonio" });
    }

    aplicar(){
    
      if(this.state.id=="rojo"){
        alert("ut escogio rojo")
      }else if(this.state.id=="blanco"){
        alert("ut esocgio blanco")
      }else if(this.state.id=="purpura"){
        alert("ut esocgio purpura")
      }else if(this.state.id=="fiesta"){
        alert("ut esocgio fiesta")
      }else if(this.state.id=="matrimonio"){
        alert("ut esocgio matrimonio")
      }
      else if(this.state.id=="rojo" && this.state.id=="matrimonio"){
        alert("ut esocgio rojo de fiesta")
      }
  
    }
    
  render() {
  

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>ROJO</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkRojo} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxRojo()}/>
      <Text>BLANCO</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkBlanco} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxBlanco()}/>
      <Text>PURPURA</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkPurpura} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxPurpura()}/>
      <Text>FIESTA</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkFiesta} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxFiesta()}/>
      <Text>MATRIMONIO</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkMatrimonio} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxMatrimonio()}/>

      <Button title="aplicar" onPress={() =>this.aplicar()}></Button>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tus opciones pueden ser perfectamente un array de esta forma:

```
opciones:[
    {check:false,id:"Rojo"},
    {check:false,id:"Blanco"},
    {check:false,id:"Purpura"},
    {check:false,id:"Fiesta"},
    {check:false,id:"Matrimonio"}
]
```

Y podrías mostrarlas con un `map` de esta forma:

```
{
    this.state.opciones.map(el=>{
      return (
        <div key={el.id}>
          <Text>{el.id}</Text>
          <CheckBox value={el.check} onChange={this.onSeleccion}/>
        </div>
      )
    })
}
```

Con esto solo necesitas una sola función para el `onChange`, en este ejemplo seria `onSeleccion`, dicha función se vería:

```
onSeleccion(e){
    let {name,value}=e.target;
    let opciones=[...this.state.opciones];
    let indice=opciones.findIndex(el=>el.id == name)
    opciones[indice].check=!opciones[indice].check;
    this.setState({
      optiones:[...opciones]
    })
  }
```

Donde se busca la opción clickeada con `let indice=opciones.findIndex(el=>el.id == name)`, para posterior cambiarle de estado: `opciones[indice].check = !opciones[indice].check;`.

Por ultimo nos faltaría obtener los datos seleccionados para esto seria suficiente con un `filter` :

```
let selecciones=this.state.opciones.filter(el=>el.check)
```

Y listo con todo esto tu código debería de funcionar.

El ejemplo completo y funcionando lo puedes ver en:[este proyecto de codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sound-dn96z?file=/src/App.js:515-571)

Comment: muchas gracias!